# Can I include language course fee into my relocation package?

Tags: relocation, language-course

I have relocated to Paris office of my company. I started taking french lessons in the evening. I am wondering if it is something I can add to my relocation reimbursement package?

I have a fix relocation package which I can claim by submitting reports of the expenditure.

So,

1. Did anyone of you added language course fee to relocation before?
2. Is it correct to ask it?

**Update:**
I went through the relocation document regarding Do(s) and Don't(s), but looks like it is not something so common that they give it a specific space in the rule book, so wanted to know the general trend?

Comment: Won't this depend upon the internal rules and procedures and informal customs of the company that employs you?

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica I went through the relocation document regarding Do(s) and Don't(s), but looks like it is not something so common that they give it a specific space in the rule book, so wanted to know the general trend?

Comment: Perhaps I'm wrong, but given the different political, cultural, and economic histories and circumstances of companies that have staff in France, I think it very unlikely that a general rule or approach will be found.

Comment: This is a question that only your company can answer.